# window.location.href doesn't work in Ipad and Iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile

I used Google Login API in form. After logged in user, I used `window.location.href` to redirect user to another page, but it is not working in `iPad` and `iPhone`.

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/test";
```

Comment: Probably because you are doing something before it. In other words, the **first** step in your click event handler must be `window.location.href = "https://example.com";`.

Answer (score 5):

remove `href` as shown below

```
window.location = "http://example.com/test";
```

Comment: sets the URL in the address bar but doesn't refresh/load the page.